# Request url in Cloudflare worker only updates on page refresh

Tags: gatsby, cloudflare, worker

I have a Gatsby application and I am trying to run some redirects in the worker.
I get the URL from the request and match the pathname with the given route.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    ...

    const url = new URL(event.request.url);

    if (url.pathname.includes('/routexyz'))
        return Response.redirect(....);

    ...
});
```

The problem is that this code only works on the page refresh. If I navigate to this route internally from some other page in the application, it doesn’t work. Even the request URL doesn’t change as well.
What could be possibly wrong here? Also, could it be the Gatsby link routing issue as it stops the complete rerendering of the page for the internal routes?

Any help is much appreciated.